# AngularJS ng-bind-html and components

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS ver. 1.6.8.

I have a component I have built called icons. To incorporate it in a page I just add `<icons></icons>` and the component is inserted into the page.

Now I have a scope variable that holds html, and part of that html is the previously mentioned code `<icons></icons>`.

When I use ng-bind-html it doesn't compile the component and instead just shows `<icons></icons>` as text.

I have tried using angular-bind-html-compile ([link](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile/blob/master/angular-bind-html-compile.js)) but that didn't help.

All of the solutions I found seem to support angular pre made directives and not newly formed components.

Happy to hear of any possible solutions.

Comment: please post your relevant code

Comment: Provide a demo that uses `ng-bind-html-compile` that isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you do the following on your scope variable which holds the html code? This is a common mistake.

`$scope.trustAsHtml('<div>....')`

But as mentioned before, without your code it is hard to figure out the problem.

Comment: That's the answer. Thanks.